# Prestashop: uploading CSV programmatically

Tags: prestashop

Is their any quick way to upload a CSV using Prestashop's default CSV importer but from code (external module) and not the GUI-way?

I find the lack of documentation pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Prestashop's documentation is very frustrating. I'd look at extending the `classes/module/ImportModule.php` file for your situation.

Comment: Hm, I decided to go with their RESTful API before seeing this answer but now that I check that file it might be useful for anyone who would like to go with something similiar.

Comment: Sure. You can still put your answer and provide some details about their API in order to upload csv. Best wishes.